# TortoiseSVN (Subversion Client)?

Tags: software-recommendation, nautilus, svn, rabbitvcs

Is there any software like TortoiseSVN for Subversion client that can be integrated with Nautilus?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You want RabbitVCS: http://rabbitvcs.org/ It's a program that integrates with Nautilus and is even inspired by tortoise svn. There is news it will support git in the future, although no news on bzr support (which is what Ubuntu developers like to use)

[image]

Comment: It got GIT support already.