# Connecting to a Windows SVN server from Ubuntu

Tags: windows, svn

I need to access an SVN repo hosted on a Windows machine from Ubuntu. However, even if I supply the proper credentials, it denies me access, apparently because Windows does not allow Linux connections (as they told me); sure enough, I got in when I tried to checkout from my XP partition. While I have my box dual-booted, it is inconvenient to switch just for SVN.

So, does anyone know how I can access that SVN repo from Ubuntu? I've tried installing TortoiseSVN and Windows Subversion under Wine but I can't even get them to run; they were asking for some DLLs that I don't know how to supply. I've thought of installing a virtual XP just for SVN but I consider that too extreme and I'd be glad if anyone can advise a simpler workaround.

**Hopefully-relevant note:** When I access the repo on Windows, I use the prefix `file://`; `svn://` and `https://` results to an error. (So, AFAIK, I'm accessing the repo via our LAN.)

Comment: There is no need to install windows tools for Subversion with Wine.

Comment: "...because Windows does not allow Linux connections (as they told me)" Who told you that?

Comment: Been told from coworkers who have been using Linux at work longer than me. They're from another team and they told me they migrated their SVN server from Linux when they switched as well.

Comment: pls pass this [link](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/subversion-users/201003.mbox/%3Cb26be6d91003170847m1b0b2a70re0e8984bdd42bb59@mail.gmail.com%3E) to whoever is incharge of maintaining your server, hopefully it will convince them to switch before $#!+ hits the fan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any such restriction. My previous job used a SVN repository hosted on a Windows server and accessed by mostly Ubuntu clients using the commandline `svn` that came with it. It was hosted via `https://` and not `svn://` but that should not matter either.

Can you be more specific on what happens when it denies you access?

Do you have any info on which server is used to host the repository? My previous job used [Visual SVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/)

p.s. some more confirmation from more [authoritative sources](http://www.svnforum.org/threads/34709-Will-a-Linux-SVN-Client-work-with-a-Windows-Server)

Comment: Well, this might be the thing; you see, when I'm accessing the repo at Windows, the prefix I use is `file://`. I've mistakenly tried using  the `svn` prefix once and got an error.

Comment: `file://`? thats weird.. that protocol is meant to be used only if your repository and working copy is on the same machine afaik.. unless the repo is hosted via file sharing.. which sounds like a bad idea..... Some more info from [authoritative sources](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/subversion-users/201003.mbox/%3Cb26be6d91003170847m1b0b2a70re0e8984bdd42bb59@mail.gmail.com%3E)

Comment: Wow. Thanks for that link. I'd be sure to relay that. But for the meantime, are you aware of how I can workaround this? `file://` does not seem compatible when host is Windows and client is on Linux (unless I misunderstand). Or am I left with no choice till we're not using `file://` anymore?

Comment: Im sorry, I have no workarounds for you since im still not sure why it doesnt work for you. [This Link](http://svn.haxx.se/users/archive-2007-10/0884.shtml) seems to prove that it is indeed possible to connect to a svn`file://` repository that is hosted via samba at least.. close but no cigar perhaps. It also gives you yet another warning against this style of usage.

Comment: Oh well...guess I'd just have to persuade better and faster. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can install [Subversion](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/subversion/) [image: Install Subversion] via terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>T</kbd>.:

```
sudo apt-get install subversion
```

Now you can checkout the repository (example).:

```
svn checkout http://localhost/svn/projekt1/trunk/ /home/user/projekt1
```

[image: Subversion example image]

**See:** [Subversion @ help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Subversion) and [TortoiseSVN (Subversion Client)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22070/tortoisesvn-subversion-client)